# How do I avoid that my App enters optimization on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-powermanager

Smart manager kills an app that hasn't been used for 3 days. My app does some background work and hence, the user doesn't need to open it.

What can I do so that it doesn't enter app optimization mode ( Android OS 5.0.2, 5.1.1)

Comment: I found a workaround, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54945943/704872

Answer (score 10):

I found an array with the packages that are in the whitelist from Smart Manager. There is some kind of partnership with developers and Samsung.

Galaxy S7 Android N, Smart Manager its package name now is "**com.samsung.android.lool**"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setClassName("com.samsung.android.lool", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);


<string-array name="exclude_from_spcm">
    <item>com.sds.mdmain</item>
    <item>com.whatsapp</item>
    <item>com.facebook.orca</item>
    <item>com.tencent.mm</item>
    <item>com.skype.raider</item>
    <item>com.viber.voip</item>
    <item>jp.naver.line.android</item>
    <item>com.kakao.talk</item>
    <item>com.snapchat.android</item>
    <item>com.sgiggle.production</item>
    <item>kik.android</item>
    <item>com.kakao.story</item>
    <item>com.nhn.android.band</item>
    <item>com.btb.minihompy</item>
    <item>com.sec.chatonblue</item>
    <item>com.sds.mobiledesk</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.spay</item>
    <item>com.sec.android.app.shealth</item>
    <item>com.z7.samsung.mobiledesk.z7</item>
    <item>com.z7.samsung.mobiledesk.Z7</item>
    <item>com.sds.mysinglesquare</item>
    <item>com.samsung.uready.agent</item>
    <item>com.sds.mobile.mdm.client.MDMManager</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.watchmanager</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.wms</item>
    <item>com.samsung.accessory.goproviders</item>
    <item>com.samsung.accessory.saproviders</item>
    <item>com.sec.android.sidesync30</item>
    <item>com.amc.ui</item>
    <item>com.sec.wecontacts</item>
    <item>com.bns.wecontacts</item>
    <item>com.sec.weagent</item>
    <item>com.sec.wetester</item>
    <item>com.samsung.dbs.service</item>
    <item>com.kddi.android.videopass</item>
    <item>com.ktcs.whowho</item>
    <item>com.google.android.wearable.app</item>
    <item>com.google.android.projection.gearhead</item>
    <item>com.sec.chaton.secure</item>
    <item>com.estsoft.alyac</item>
    <item>com.estsoft.alyac.tablet</item>
    <item>com.coremobility.app.vnotes</item>
    <item>com.kineto.smartwifi</item>
    <item>msgplus.jibe.sca</item>
    <item>com.locationlabs.sparkle.yellow.pre</item>
    <item>com.locationlabs.v3client</item>
    <item>com.oem.smartwifisupport</item>
    <item>com.wsandroid.suite.vodaemea</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.sn.vpn</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.smhs</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.vodafone360updates</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.netperform.full</item>
    <item>com.vf_nqt.client</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.messaging</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.safetynet.core</item>
    <item>at.mobilkom.android.meina1</item>
    <item>al.myvodafone.android</item>
    <item>com.zentity.vodafone</item>
    <item>com.appseleration.android.selfcare</item>
    <item>com.myvodafone.android</item>
    <item>hu.mito.android.vodafone</item>
    <item>com.VodafoneIreland.MyVodafone</item>
    <item>it.vodafone.my190</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.android</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.mCare</item>
    <item>be.belgacom.hello</item>
    <item>ro.vodafone.mcare.android</item>
    <item>es.vodafone.mobile.mivodafone</item>
    <item>com.swisscom.myswisscom</item>
    <item>com.myvodafoneapp</item>
    <item>za.co.vodacom.android.app</item>
    <item>com.appseleration.speedtest</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.tmplus</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.widget</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.engineering</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.enterprise</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.apc</item>
    <item>com.radioopt.network</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.accesorystore</item>
    <item>at.mobilkom.android.a1apps</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.myaccessories</item>
    <item>com.swisscom.scappslauncher</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.directaccessories</item>
    <item>hr.infinum.mojvip</item>
    <item>com.vodafone.appstore.sa</item>
    <item>com.skt.skaf.a000as00tm</item>
    <item>com.kt.mtmoney</item>
    <item>com.lgt.tmoney</item>
    <item>com.ebcard.skcashbee</item>
    <item>com.kt.cashbee</item>
    <item>com.lguplus.cashbee</item>
    <item>com.hs.govsns.mobile</item>
    <item>com.oculus.home</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.hmt.vrsvc</item>
    <item>com.oculus.oculus360photos</item>
    <item>com.oculus.oculus360videos</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.vrsetupwizard</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.vrsetupwizardstub</item>
    <item>com.oculus.horizon</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.vr.gallery</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.vr.video</item>
    <item>com.oculus.cinema</item>
    <item>com.oculus.systemactivities</item>
    <item>com.facebook.appmanager</item>
    <item>com.facebook.system</item>
    <item>com.ipg.gguide.dcm_app.android</item>
    <item>com.ipg.gguide.dcm_wifi_app.android</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.iconcier</item>
    <item>jp.co.nttdocomo.ichannel</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.osv</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.anmane</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.anmane2</item>
    <item>com.rsupport.rs.activity.ntt</item>
    <item>jp.co.nttdocomo.android.gs.utility2_sha2</item>
    <item>jp.co.nttdocomo.android.gs.utility2</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.mascot</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.docomosimplehome</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.lac</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.settings.lac</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.cloudstorageservice</item>
    <item>com.mcafee.vsm_android_dcm</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.gs.utility_sha2</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.gs.utility</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.accountwipe</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.messagedl</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.homeagent</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.toruca</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.photocollection</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.photoviewer</item>
    <item>jp.id_credit_sp.android</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.apnmng</item>
    <item>jp.co.nttdocomo.contentsheadline</item>
    <item>com.mcafee.safecall.docomo</item>
    <item>jp.dmapnavi.navi02</item>
    <item>com.uievolution.gguide.android</item>
    <item>com.showcasegig.devlawson</item>
    <item>jp.co.mcdonalds.android</item>
    <item>jp.co.lawson.activity</item>
    <item>kr.co.nexdigm.mdm.s</item>
    <item>kr.co.nexdigm.mdm.agent</item>
    <item>com.sktelecom.ssm</item>
    <item>com.sktelecom.ssmpush</item>
    <item>com.ebcard.cashbeew.s</item>
    <item>com.life360.android.safetymapd</item>
    <item>com.fsp.android.friendlocator</item>
    <item>com.fsp.android.c</item>
    <item>com.fsp.android.h</item>
    <item>com.fsp.android.phonetracker</item>
    <item>com.life360.android.note4</item>
    <item>com.life360.android.s6</item>
    <item>fr.freemobile.android.vvm</item>
    <item>fr.freemobile.android.mobilecompagnon</item>
    <item>kr.co.bnkbank.push.customer</item>
    <item>kr.co.bnkbank.push.employee</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.sbanking</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.speedup</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.smartcaremgr</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.smartfund</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.missionbanking</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.mobilebankbook</item>
    <item>com.safeon.approval</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.sbizbank</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.trade.copper</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.dingdong</item>
    <item>com.shinhan.shb2chd</item>
    <item>com.shcard.smartpay</item>
    <item>com.shinhancard.smartshinhan</item>
    <item>com.shinhancard.smartshinhan.mini</item>
    <item>com.wr.alrim</item>
    <item>com.IBK.SmartPush.app</item>
    <item>com.hanafn.push.agent</item>
    <item>com.hanabank.ebk.channel.android.hananbank</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.memo</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.snote</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.pinboard</item>
    <item>com.sds.mobile.mdm.client.MDMManager</item>
    <item>com.sds.emm.client</item>
    <item>com.sds.emm.client.visitor</item>
    <item>gogolook.callgogolook2</item>
    <item>com.nhn.android.webtoon</item>
    <item>com.naver.linewebtoon</item>
    <item>com.naver.vapp</item>
    <item>com.navercorp.android.ttsapp</item>
    <item>com.nhn.android.music</item>
    <item>net.daum.android.daum</item>
    <item>com.daumkakao.android.brunchapp</item>
    <item>com.kakao.page</item>
    <item>com.vaultmicro.kidsnote</item>
    <item>com.orange.vvm</item>
    <item>com.telenor.mbedriftsnett</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.app.scharm</item>
    <item>net.ib.android.smcard</item>
    <item>com.samsungcard.certi</item>
    <item>kr.co.samsungcard.mpocket</item>
    <item>com.samsungcard.shopping</item>
    <item>com.samsungcard.baby</item>
    <item>sc.chn.hom.msa.ga</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.email.provider</item>
    <item>com.samsung.oh</item>
    <item>com.sec.android.app.sbrowser</item>
    <item>com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal</item>
    <item>com.icq.mobile.client</item>
    <item>com.my.mail</item>
    <item>com.vkontakte.android</item>
    <item>ru.mail.mailapp</item>
    <item>ru.ok.android</item>
    <item>com.google.android.apps.tachyon</item>
    <item>ru.mail</item>
    <item>com.lacoon.security.fox</item>
    <item>com.google.android.apps.fireball</item>
    <item>com.sds.mms.ui</item>
    <item>com.mcafee.android.scanservice</item>
    <item>com.android.services.telephony.common</item>
    <item>com.samsungcard.android.oap</item>
    <item>com.sec.android.app.ocr3</item>
    <item>com.sec.android.app.ocr4</item>
    <item>com.mediatek.BlueMagpie</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.game.gametools</item>
    <item>it.h3g.areaclienti3</item>
    <item>com.skt.prod.cloud</item>
    <item>com.turkcell.bip</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.intelligence.executormanager</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.hcebridge</item>
    <item>jp.id_credit_sp.android.devappli</item>
    <item>com.knb.psb</item>
    <item>com.knb.csb</item>
    <item>com.knb.bsp</item>
    <item>com.knb.bdr</item>
    <item>com.diotek.sec.lookup.dictionary</item>
    <item>com.samsung.android.onlinevideo</item>
    <item>com.oculus.systemdriver</item>
    <item>com.oculus.gearchina</item>
    <item>com.oculus.systemservices</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.iconcier_contents</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.socialphonebook</item>
    <item>com.nttdocomo.android.portablesim</item>
    <item>com.sktelecom.ttalk</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Where did you find this list?

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, there is currently no way to prevent this.

The only thing you can do is instruct users to disable optimization for your app.

I did some research about this myself not long ago, here are some links I saved that might be interesting for you

https://news.samsung.com/global/smart-manager-the-way-to-keep-your-galaxy-smartphone-as-good-as-new-always

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/smart-manager-kills-my-alarms/202/288300?boardName=General&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=3

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/samsung-smart-manager-is-preventing-alarmmanager-to-work-correctly/201/288546?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000001

Also, here is a code snippet that launches the smart manager app's BatteryActivity (if it's installed) to help users to disable the optimization:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.sm", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"));
try {
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Smart manager not installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: So even if you run a foreground service that shows a notification in the notification tray, but you don't open the app for many days, you can still go into app optimization? @Tim Castelijns

Comment: @lyc001 I'm not 100% sure about foreground services, since I use a background service myself. But yes all my testing and reseach show that if a user does not open the app within X days then samsung will stop all activity belonging to that your app

Comment: If I want to simulate the behavior, by going to battery optimization and choosing "always optimizing" for my app, I still can connect to it and do some background work. Do you know how we can simulate app optimization mode without having to wait for 3 days? @Tim Castelijns

Comment: @lyc001 sorry, I don't know if that's possible. Perhaps there is an option in the ddms tool, but I haven't used that much so I can't tell you any details

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you know how to go to the list of apps using battery instead of battery manager. com.samsung.android.sm.ui.applocking.AppLockingViewActivity

Comment: @Fakher same way just replaced the string. If it doesn't work, the screen is not externally accessible.

Comment: I try it, it throws a securityException !!! saying that permission denial !

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Is there any way to set app by default "Turned Off". Because i installed the `viber`, `whatsapp` and `Messenger` (facebook) these app's  "Power saving" setting is by default `Turned off`.

Comment: @MukeshKumar As far as I know everything is turned on by default. If these apps are not, perhaps SmartManager has criteria by which it decides what to do with an app, or maybe facebook etc have deals with Samsung. I don't know

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns.

Comment: If battery optimization is enabled, push notification will work?

Comment: @phnmnn push notifications (at least high priority ones) always work

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I have a navigation application. Geofences on Samsung devices after a certain time stop working(on other devices works perfect), seems the problem caused by Smart manager. Can i use push notification to update geofence topology after my app got deactivated by Smart manager?

Comment: Is there not any API so that an application can automatically read the list of apps that have been put to sleep?

Comment: use

`"com.samsung.android.sm", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"` on Android L and 
`"com.samsung.android.lool", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"` on Android N

Source https://code.briarproject.org/briar/briar/issues/1100

Comment: use `"com.samsung.android.lool", "com.samsung.android.sm.battery.ui.BatteryActivity"` on Android 10 (at least on my Samsung S10e)