# Schedule job when app is running

Tags: android

I built an application where I need to do some queued up work periodically. 
I was using `JobScheduler` to run a periodic job, but I have several problems with it (smartmanager of samsung disables it, sometimes not running for a long time...)

For explanation: The user interacts with the app (click a button, take a photo...) and the app queues it in a sqlite database. The `JobScheduler` is here to upload it periodically to our servers.

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to whitelist your app?

Comment: that works, but it's a company app and i can't control over 100 devices.
if an employee enables it, i can't know

Comment: A foreground notification is useful in some cases. AlarmManager is also prevented from killing but it's a different use case.

Comment: It's not so easy for our employees to whitelist it. So a notification does not help either.

Comment: Processes SmartManager covers Samsung and few other devices. Also, people may or may not choose to enable it.

Comment: Here's a useful thread I would like to share it with you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205106/how-do-i-avoid-that-my-app-enters-optimization-on-samsung-devices

Comment: If you can check If the smart manager is installed on the device and respectively display a nice little suggestive message to turn it off in order to provide best services, I think that would be helpful.