# ACL_CONNECTED / ACL_DISCONNECTED doesn't always received

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an application in which I need to listen to bluetooth connection/disconnection events.

The broadcasts are getting received most of the time, but not always.

My logs also support this.

I can see in my logs that sometimes I'm getting 2 or 3 ACL_CONNECTED events in a row (for the same device!) without getting ACL_DISCONNECTED in between, and vice versa.

Here's the declaration in the manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name=".receivers.BluetoothBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Is someone familiar with this issue?

**Note (06/20/18):**

Most of my tests are done with Samsung devices.

Samsung has its own battery optimisation mechanism, as can be seen in those posts:

[Samsung "App optimisation" feature kills background applications after 3 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850109/samsung-app-optimisation-feature-kills-background-applications-after-3-days)

[How do I avoid that my App enters optimization on Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205106/how-do-i-avoid-that-my-app-enters-optimization-on-samsung-devices)

It seems that the problem is somehow related to this Samsung thing.

According to my logs, it seems like that the inconsistent broadcasts problem, really starts to appear after 3 days

Thanks!