# BroadcastReceiver triggered by AlarmManager manager is triggered upon app being opened

Tags: android

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` specified via app manifest which creates a notification. I have an `AlarmManager.setRepeating` alarm which calls the `BroadcastReceiver` every couple of hours to create the notification.

I set the repeating alarm, close my app, and it works fine for the fist few notifications. However, after the first few notifications get delivered successfully, they stop. Once I open the app again, the notification suddenly arrives.

Is this the phone putting my app to sleep? Or something else? I'm testing on a samsung device btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the application going to **sleep**. My application has exactly the same behavior on later versions of android (by the way, also Samsung). To solve this problem, might be helpful this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254010/11937776).

Also you can add your application to never sleeping apps list in settings of battery usage limits (Settings > Battery and Device Care > Battery > Background Usage Limits > Never Sleeping apps)

---

Hope it solved your problem. Happy coding <3