# Stop receiving location in background after few days in some new devices meanwhile in others works OK

Tags: java, android, location, google-api-client, google-location-services

I made an app that mostly works as a tracker. The issue is that works correctly in almost every device i test for days and in background.
Test in:

Motorola XT1563 , working since 2018-02-02

Motorola XT1635-02 , since 2018-01-24

Samsung E7, since 2018-01-19

This works perfectly, even if i reboot, lost connection, turn on/off location...

But in Samsung SM-G930F and Samsung SM-G950F works OK in background with acceptable frecuency for 3-4 Days but after that stops sending locations and never know nothing about the device at least the user opens the app again.

i know the new [background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html) so i had to make some changes to my app. I follow [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/#0) guide for that.

Location request:

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(Constants.UPDATE_FASTEST_INTERVAL)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    }
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();}
```

To start location updates

```
public void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (isLocationPermissionGranted()){

            Intent mRequestLocationUpdatesBroadcaster = new Intent(mContext, JobIntentBroadcaster.class);
            mPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, mRequestLocationUpdatesBroadcaster,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mPendingIntent);
```

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class JobIntentBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, LocationIntentService.class);
        LocationIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
    }
}
```

The JobIntentService(used before new android version):

```
public class LocationIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    static final int JOB_ID = 1000;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        Log.d("enqueueWork","Se llama al jobintent service!");
        enqueueWork(context, LocationIntentService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String mLastUpdateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        if (location != null) { 
            send to server
        }
```

How can i handle this problem with new devices?

Is it necessary to make notifications (foreground service) to fix that?

Is this a consequence of new android versions or a Samsung battery safety thing?

**UPDATE**

I find out this problem is caused by Samsung Battery Optimization. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850109/samsung-app-optimisation-feature-kills-background-applications-after-3-days) is the close solution i found but don't fit my requirements so the problem persist...

Comment: did you end up finding a solution? I'm having the exact same issues specifically on Samsung devices

Comment: @SameerJJ for external reasons this feature was removed so no. I couldn't manage to avoid the killing. Try asking in [Samsung Developers Forum](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/en?boardName=SDK&searchSubIdAll=&searchSubId=0000000047&topCtgy=01&searchType=ALL&searchText=).

Answer (score 0):

I've had some better but not perfect results using the new `WorkerManager` class in Android X, which leverages `AlarmManager`, `JobScheduler` or others internally depending on some undisclosed factors.

Another option to explore would be Firebase Job Dispatcher

Comment: I forgot to update. I discovered (reading i don't know where) the Samsungs phones have an "Battery optimization" feature. This  causes application kill if the app was not open in the last 3/4 days (depending on the configuration).